# Ubuntu WSL: symlink to windows share with specific name

Tags: windows, ubuntu, symbolic-link, wsl2

I'm trying to set up a new Windows environment with WSL. My previous distro became corrupt, so to somewhat compartmentalise things I'm creating a couple of VHDs on the host system and attaching them. This has the great advantage of me being able to share my folders over the network via SMB, and also access them directly in WSL via things like /mnt/f.

However all of my previous code was set up with paths relative to a folder in my home directory, e.g. ~/project/ml-code/. I have a VHD attached on the host called ml-code.vhdx which is the mounted as drive H:, so it shows up in WSL as /mnt/h. However to reduce friction with my existing code I want to symlink /mnt/h as ~/projects/ml-code, which I've attempted with the following command:

```
ln -s /mnt/h/ ~/projects/ml-code/
```

However this results in the following folder structure:

```
-- projects
---- ml-code
------ h
-------- file.py
```

Whereas I want:

```
-- projects
---- ml-code
------ file.py
```

How can I achieve this? I'm so close!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, I think:

```
ln -sfT /mnt/f ~/projects/ml-data
```

This behaves strangely on the Windows side, but on the WSL side it's perfect.